# How to combine inotify with tail command to print last line of every modified file

Tags: bash, inode, inotify

I have this command this shows me when a file has been modified under a concrete directory (excluding some paths):

```bsh
inotifywait -m -q -r --format '%T % e %w%f' --excludei '/trash/' --timefmt '%d/%m/%Y-%H:%M:%S%z' /my/monitored/folder
```

Is there a way to combine this (or a similar) command with `tail`, so I can retrieve the last line of each modified file? It is important that this combination outputs the file's path and the last line added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your question you say that you want to scan if a file has been *modified*, but in your command there's no event specified.

So my answer will use the `modify` event:

```bsh
inotifywait -m -q -r \
  --format '%T % e %w%f' \
  --excludei '/trash/' \
  --timefmt '%d/%m/%Y-%H:%M:%S%z' /my/monitored/folder | \
   while IFS=' ' read -r time event file; do
    echo "file: $file"
    echo "modified: $time"
    last_line=$(tail -1 "$file")
    echo "last line: $last_line"
    echo
  done
```

Wich will output something like this:

```
file: /path/file.txt
modified: 17/02/2021-09:17:02-0300
last line: foo
```